# Copy contacts from SIM memory to Phone memory

Tags: contacts, nokia-lumia-730

I have lumia 730, and on the SIM card are contacts. I am unable to copy the SIM contacts from to Phone. And also, is there a way to display my contacts like SIM contacts only, Phone memory contacts only, or both?

Comment: Also see the official how-to at http://www.windowsphone.com/en-GB/how-to/wp8/people/import-contacts-from-my-old-phone